# Edit User page in PHP and PHPMYSQL using Array Drop Down Selection

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to ask why every time i try to call programme it doesn't show the results? I'm trying to create edit user page which means i will call back the database but mine doesn't show up.

**Here's my Edit User code i have problem with row4**

```
// Retrieve the user's information:
$q = "SELECT first_name, last_name, phone, email , programme FROM users WHERE user_id=$id";     
$r = @mysql_query ($q);

if (mysql_num_rows($r) == 1) { // Valid user ID, show the form.

    // Get the user's information:
    $row = mysql_fetch_array ($r, MYSQL_NUM);

    // Create the form:
    echo '<div align="center"/div><form action="edit_user.php" method="post">
<p>First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" size="15" maxlength="15" value="' . $row[0] . '" /></p>
<p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" size="15" maxlength="30" value="' . $row[1] . '" /></p>
<p>Phone No: <input type="text" name="phone" size="20" maxlength="60" value="' . $row[2] . '"  /> </p>
<p>Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" size="20" maxlength="60" value="' . $row[3] . '"  /> </p>
<p>Programme: <name="programme" size="20" maxlength="60" value="' . $row[4] . '"  /> </p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '" />
</form>';
```

**Here's my Registration code because i used drop down so i can't call drop down back in edit user page that include database for programme registered**

```
<?php # Script 3.5 - Registration Form
$page_title = 'Registration Form';
include ('./includes_css/header.html');
?>


<div align="center"><h2>Registration Form</h2>
<form action="register.php" method="post">

<legend>Enter your information in the form below:</legend><br/>

<p><b>First Name:</b> <input type="text" size="21" name="first_name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) echo $_POST['first_name']; ?>"/></p>
<p><b>Last Name:</b> <input type="text" size="21"name="last_name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['last_name'])) echo $_POST['last_name']; ?>"/></p>
<p><b>Phone No:</b> <input type="text" size="22"name="phone" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['phone'])) echo $_POST['phone']; ?>"/></p>
<p><b>Email Address:</b> <input type="text" size="18"name="email" /value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>"/></p>
<p><b>Programme:</b> <name="programme" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['programme'])) echo $_POST['programme']; ?>"/>
<?php

$programme = array ('null' => 'SELECT','BIMD', 'BSE', 'BCEM', 'BCA', 'DIM', 'DCNET',
'DIT', 'DIA');
// Make the programme pull-down menu.
echo '<select name="programme">';
foreach ($programme as $key => $value) {
echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>\n";
}
echo '</select>';
?>
<div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" /></div>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
</form>
```

I have problem with Edit User page (Program doesn't show up).

[image: You can see here is the Edit User page]

[image: This one is my Registration page]

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated in PHP5 and removed in PHP7. Please use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: I'm using old version that's why i used mysql, i just need my programme to be shown in Edit User page.  @C0dekid TQ

Comment: @BlackDahlia, it would help if you [add code to show all errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings) and then report which one you are seeing.

Comment: @Mark 

<p>Programme: <name="programme" size="20" maxlength="60" value="' . $row[4] . '"  /> </p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>

This is the problem i guess , because this result is from array but i can't call it back when i try to edit page and update.